# Android Lollipop Decryption using AES is not working properly

Tags: android, encryption, aes, android-5.0-lollipop

Till kitkat, encryption/decryption is working good but in lollipop it decrypts only partial data.

I don't have problem with encryption because I encrypted a file with lollipop and decrypts it with kitkat it works fine but not vice versa.

Here is the code.

**Encryption code**

```
Encrypt(BufferedInputStream is, File destfile, String passcode) {
        bis = is;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(destfile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);
        this.passcode = passcode;
    }

    static void encrypt() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
    NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {

        // Length is 16 byte
        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(passcode.getBytes(), "AES");

        // Create cipher
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
        // Wrap the output stream
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
        // Write bytes
        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[1024];
        while ((b = bis.read(d)) != -1) {
            cos.write(d, 0, b);
        }
        // Flush and close streams.
        cos.flush();
        cos.close();
        bis.close();
    }
```

**Decryption code**

```
public Decrypt(String path, String pathcode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        filepath = path;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
            this.passcode = pathcode;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    static String decrypt() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
    NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {

        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(passcode.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
        int size = fis.available();
        byte[] resdata = new byte[size];
        cis.read(resdata, 0, size);
        String newres = new String(resdata, "UTF-8").trim();
        //write("decrypted_file.xhtml",newres);  
        if(fis!=null)
        {
        fis.close();
        }
        if(cis!=null)
            cis.close();
        return newres;
    }
```

What's the problem in this code? Do I need to do anything more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`available()` doesn't necessarily return the length of the entire stream, just the estimated number of bytes that can be read without blocking. So, use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to store the bytes and then covert to a byte array:

```
CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int bytesRead;
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
while ((bytesRead = cis.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
    buffer.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
}
buffer.flush();
byte[] resdata = buffer.toByteArray();
String newres = new String(resdata, "UTF-8").trim();
```

Comment: Its working!!! great :-) . Many thanks to you. But why available() working before lollipop and not working in lollipop.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know exactly why available() stopped working in Lollipop, but my guess is that Google changed the way the internal buffering works in CipherInputStream, or possibly they weren't even using buffering before Lollipop so previously the available bytes always was equal to the total file/stream length.